# Why isn't Bessel's correction used for sample mean absolute deviation

Tags: descriptive-statistics, parameter-estimation

My understanding so far is the (unbiased) sample variance is modified by Bessel's correction to account for the fact that the first observation of $ (X-\overline X)$ in a given sample X, will always equal zero (is not "free to vary"), as i.a. the mean of the first observation and the first observation will always be the same value. So the number of deviations being averaged is n-1 instead of n.

$$
s^2= \frac{∑(X-\overline X)^2}{\rm n-1}
$$

When I look at the formula for the sample mean absolute deviation, however, it is:

$$
Mean\:Absolute\:Deviation = \frac{∑|X-\overline X|}{\rm n}
$$

Is it also possible to have an unbiased estimator here using $n-1$ and why/why not?

***Source for equations: Salvatore and Reagle, Statistics and Econometrics Second Edition - Eqs. 2.6b and 2.8b***

Comment: I think it would be useful to specify the sources of the above formulas. As for the question itself, I think that for large $n$ some people don't distinguish between the two choices

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, I have now included the source textbook.

Answer (score 1):

For the mean absolute deviation, the correction $n-1$ does not give an unbiased estimator in general.
However, it does works in some cases.

**Normal distribution** For example, take $X$ standard normally distributed.
Then, $E|X-EX|=E|X|=\sqrt{2/\pi}$.
Moreover,
$$
X_1-\bar{X}=\frac{n-1}{n}X_1-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=2}^n X_i=:Y
$$
This is random variable $Y$ has a normal distibution with mean zero, and variance:
$$
Var[Y]=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2+\frac{1}{n}
$$
So, $Y$ has the same distribution as $\sqrt{\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2+\frac{1}{n}}X_1$. We calculate:
$$
E\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i-\bar{X}|=nE|Y|=nE\left|\sqrt{\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2+\frac{1}{n}}X_1\right|
=n\sqrt{\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2+\frac{1}{n}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}
$$
$$
=\sqrt{(n-1)^2+n}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}
$$
So, an unbiased estimator for $E|X|$ is:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n-1)^2+n}}\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i-\bar{X}|
$$

**Bernoulli distribution** However, it is true for some special cases.
If $X$ is $0.5$-Bernoulli, it works.
We want to estimate $E|X-EX|$.
We have $E|X-EX|=E|X-0.5|=0.5*(0.5+0.5)=0.5$.
So, our estimator should have the same expected value.
Consider $E|X_1-\bar{X}|$.
We can write:
$$
E|X_1-\bar{X}|=E\left[1-\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\sum_{i=2}^nX_i\right)\Bigg|X_1=1\right]\frac{1}{2}+
E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=2}^nX_i\Bigg|X_1=0\right]\frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
=\frac{n-1}{2n}-E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=2}^nX_i\right]\frac{1}{2}+E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=2}^nX_i\right]\frac{1}{2}=\frac{n-1}{2n}
$$
From here, it follows that $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i-\bar{X}|$ has expectation $0.5$, hence it is an unbiased estimator for $E|X-EX|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Idontgetit! Good to know it can work. I am trying to get the intuition behind degrees of freedom; it seemed strange to me that this was the given estimator for Mean Absolute Deviation in the book, was wondering why they would provide a biased estimator for MAD, given it is at pains to emphasize the need for an n-1 demoninator to correct bias in the sample variance.

Comment: I just added the standard normal case to my answer. It appears that the correction really depends on the distribution of $X$. Generally, $n-1$ (the "degrees of freedom") is not the correct correction ;-)